# Compile Visual Studio extension that allows update instead of uninstall/install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio 2015, and I'm building the solution and installing the .vsix manually on my local machine. The problem is that every time I rebuild the package and try to install the new one it says that the extension already exists, and I have to go to extension manager, uninstall it and finally install the new version again.

What sort of consifguration do I have to use in my extension project so Visual Studio updates the currently installed extension when I try to install the updated vsix package?

Comment: Why aren't you just letting the SDK install the extension for you instead of doing it manually?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski If I understood what you meant, during development the SDK install the extension on a sandbox version of VS, the installed extension is not available to the production environment of VS.

Comment: But are you installing them back into your main instance during your build-test-debug cycle, or is this a question for "OK, I fixed some stuff, now I want to release my new extension to me for further testing?"

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Not during the build-test-debug, for this VS automatically install the extension on the sandbox version of VS. The question is about the moment I decided that some functionality is implemented and tested, then I have to deploy to my machine and some others on local netword, in this case I have to uninstall the previous version and only then VS will allow me to install the updated VSIX file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just discovered the solution, you have to increment the version in the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file, then VS will allow you to overwrite the old installed extension.

Comment: See also: [Create a private gallery for self-hosted Visual Studio extensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/create-a-private-gallery-for-self-hosted-visual-studio-extensions/).